# how to show an image in a reactive form angular from nodejs

Tags: angular, forms, image

I have a reactive form that load in the input one object from nodejs. I can show the input text of each object but I can't show an image in the form.

```
  <form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


        <div class="form-group row">
            <!-- <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + book.image }}" alt=""> -->

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col">

                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" formControlName="_id">

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!-- *ngIf="book.image && book.image !== ''" -->

            <div class="form-control">
                <!-- formControlName="image"> -->
                <input class="form-control" type="" formControlName="image">
                <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + image }}" alt="">
                <!-- <input class="form-control" type="" formControlName="image"> -->

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">title</label>
            <div class="col">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="title" [class.is-invalid]="titleNoValido">
                <small *ngIf="titleNoValido" class="text-danger">
          write the name
        </small>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">description</label>
            <div class="col">

                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" cols="80" formControlName="description" [class.is-invalid]="descripcionNoValido">
               </textarea>

                <small *ngIf="descripcionNoValido" class="text-danger">
          write the name
        </small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">author</label>
            <div class="col">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="author" [class.is-invalid]="authorNoValido">
                <small *ngIf="authorNoValido" class="text-danger">
          write the name
        </small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">price</label>
            <div class="col">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="price" [class.is-invalid]="priceNoValido">
                <small *ngIf="priceNoValido" class="text-danger">
                Write the phone number
        </small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">stock</label>
            <div class="col">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="stock" [class.is-invalid]="stockNoValido">
                <small *ngIf="priceNoValido" class="text-danger">
                Write the phone number
        </small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Imagen</label>
            <angular-file-uploader [config]="afuConfig" (ApiResponse)="upload($event)">
            </angular-file-uploader>
            <!-- <input class="form-control" type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"> -->

            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="save()">save image</a>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="input-group col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
        Send
      </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

how I can get the image in formcontrolname="image"?
with this function I load the object in the form

```
getBook()
{
  this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
    let id = params['id'];
    this.bookservice.getBook(id).subscribe(
      response =>
      {
        if(!response.book)
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/listbooks']);
        }
        else
        {
          this.book = response.book;
          this.forma.controls['_id'].setValue(response.book._id); 
          this.forma.controls['title'].setValue(response.book.title);
          this.forma.controls['description'].setValue(response.book.description);
          this.forma.controls['author'].setValue(response.book.author);
          this.forma.controls['stock'].setValue(response.book.stock);
          this.forma.controls['price'].setValue(response.book.price);
          this.forma.controls['image'].setValue(response.book.image);

          console.log(this.book);
        }
      }
    )
  });
}
```

I only show in the input one text = the name of image with .jpg
src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + image }}" in the src I can't get the image.

Comment: can you share the image response of api ?

Comment: params {
  _id: '5f4547a23ef14d1ad547e5c4',
  date: '2020-08-25T17:17:22.461Z',
  title: 'jkjlkjlkj',
  description: 'kljlkjlkj',
  author: 'kljlkj',
  price: 555,
  image: '_pvSWlLP26XggTxS0KCtn3qu.png',
  stock: 5555,
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Is this the request or response ?

Comment: src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + book.image }}" this is the request works in other component not here

Comment: why is it `'avatar/' + image` and not `'avatar/' + book.image` like in the other example?

Comment: ..this.forma.patchValue(response.book) would be a bit more efficient by the way..

Comment: I tried some things to solve the issue but it is book.image (image property of book object)

Comment: I can print _pvSWlLP26XggTxS0KCtn3qu.png in image input but it is not an image

Comment: ok mikeone thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug adding in the component.ts in constructor() `this.url = global.url` (this get the url in the backend)

also I did in component.html

```
  <div class="">
        <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + imgURL }}" alt="">
    </div>



getBook()
{
  this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
    let id = params['id'];
    this.bookservice.getBook(id).subscribe(
      response =>
      {
        if(!response.book)
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/listbooks']);
        }
        else
        {
          this.book = response.book;
          this.forma.controls['_id'].setValue(response.book._id); 
          this.forma.controls['title'].setValue(response.book.title);
          this.forma.controls['description'].setValue(response.book.description);
          this.forma.controls['author'].setValue(response.book.author);
          this.forma.controls['stock'].setValue(response.book.stock);
          this.forma.controls['price'].setValue(response.book.price);
          this.forma.controls['image'].setValue(response.book.image);
          this.imgURL = response.book.image; // I get here the name of image
          console.log(this.imgURL);
          console.log(this.book);
        }
      }
    )
  });
}
```